# How To Concatenate JavaScript Value to HTML Input 'name' Field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one variable `value` in my jQuery ready function, and I have one HTML input tag. I want this variable to be concatenated to input tag name field. Please help me.

Comment: @simplyharsh, I don't think your edit kept the original intent of the question

Comment: Yes, now it seems to match the OP's intent.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing `value` is the value you need to add

```
$('selector').attr('name', $('selector').attr('name') + value);
```

this will do

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

You can use [$.prop("id")](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) if you are.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, try [$.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var myName = 'abc';
var $el = $('input[name=xyz]');

$el.attr('name', $el.attr('name') + myName);
```